# Android Testing and Mock: add to a List

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I got the following method to test (simplyfied):

```
    public class EntryService {

           public void insertEntry(String name, int qantity) {
                Entry newEntry = new Entry(name, quantity);
                getEntries().put(id, newEntry);
                getSharedPrefsHandler().insertUpdate(newEntry, id);
           }

           public SparseArray<CartEntry> getEntries() {
                if (entries == null) {
                    cartEntries = sharedPrefsHandler.loadAll();
                }
                return cartEntries;
           }

           ...

    }
```

Here my testing class (simplyfied):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class EntryServiceTest {

   private EntryService entryService;

   @Mock private SharedPreferencesHandler sph;
   @Mock Context mMockContext;
   @Mock private SparseArray<CartEntry> spArr;

        @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        this.entryService = new EntryService(sph);
Mockito.when(entryService.getSharedPrefsHandler().loadAll()).thenReturn(spArr);
            }

    @Test
    public void insertOneEntry() {
        // Need to get the the real entry list...
        entryService.insertEntry(testEntry1, 1);
        assertEquals("Entries in list", 1, entryService.getEntries().size());

    }
}
```

Of course (because of the Mock SparseArra, this will no return an actual size of 1.

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Entries in cart  Expected :1
>   Actual   :0

Now, I my goal is to put a Entry into the SparseArray in EntryService. Because the SparseArray is null at the beginning and it will try to load with sharedPreferenceHandler.loadAll() and further in this method sharedPrefs.getAll() will be called...
Therefore I need an empty Map which is passed up to the Service, to init an empty SparseArray:

```
Mockito.when(sph.getSharedPrefs().getAll()).thenReturn(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

(Throws java.lang.NullPointerException)
If I'm trying with an empty non-mock SparseArray in the method before:

```
Mockito.when(cartService.getPrefsHandler().loadAll()).thenReturn(new SparseArray<Entry>);
```

Output: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in android.util.SparseArray not mocked.

**Summary:**
How can I use Android testing with this service class to **add** and item and check within the service class if the list has increased and "disable" (mock) other services/handler as such as SharedPreferencesHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should aim for something like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class EntryServiceTest {

   @Mock private SharedPreferencesHandler sphMock;

   @InjectMocks
   private EntryService entryService;    

    @Test
    public void insertOneEntry() {
        // Arrange
        SparceArray<Entry> sparceArray = new SparseArray<Entry>();
        Mockito.when(sphMock.loadAll()).thenReturn(sparceArray);

        // Act
        entryService.insertEntry(testEntry1, 1);

        // Assert
        assertEquals("Entries in list", 1, sparceArray.size());
        verify(sphMock).insertUpdate(
           Mockito.any(Entry.class, Mockito.any(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks to `@InjectMocks` Mockito will inject the sphMock through the consturctor out of the box.

Apart from verifying the size of the array you should also aim for verifying that the the `insert` method has been called.

Thats how i would test it.

Comment: NullPointer @ SharedPreferencesHandler.loadAll()
-> `sharedPrefs.getAll()`, sharedPrefs are null
Tried to declare: `@InjectMocks private SharedPreferencesHandler sphMock` (I think, thats what you wanted to do with the Service aswell)
public SharedPreferencesHandler(final Context context) {...}
Then i tried `Mockito.when(sphMock.getSharedPrefs().getAll()).thenReturn(map);` (1)
 But that results in a NullPointer aswell.. this time on that method (1) - but yeah null..., even with `Mockito.when(sphMock.getSharedPrefs()).thenReturn(sp);` so do you know how i get that shared prefs != null?

Comment: `@Mock private SharedPreferences sp;` did nothing...
(in addition to the last post didn't had enough space in the last post^^)

Comment: I think even I get every method working, I'm still stuck with the SparseArray... it has to be mocked, so unless I implement all the necessary methods (returns)... -.-

Comment: Add the constructor of EntryService .. add class definition and constructor of SharedPreferencesHandler. What are these.. sphMock.getSharedPrefs().getAll() ? i dont see them used in the example. There is some stuff going on that i am not aware of.. please add add all used implementation

Comment: Yeah I tried to keep it as simple as possible. sharedPrefs.getAll() ist just the normal default android method. I think this "mocking" method was not exactly what is was hoping for. Takes too much to setup and causes alot of overhead und effort to create. I think ill move my testing to "XXServiceMock" into AndroidTest. But yeah for a smaller case your Solution will work - I will accept it that way. Thanks.